# uib-progressbar text as center align

Tags: css, angular-directive, angular-bootstrap

Is there a way we can centre aligned text of `uib-progressbar`. I have tried doing `position:absolute`. But I wanted to show list of progress bar in a UI grid viz. is a scrollable content. While scrolling text remain at its place but progress bar get scroll properly.

Template

```
<uib-progressbar animate="false" value="30">
    <span class="content">30% (3/10)</span>
</uib-progressbar>
```

Style

```
.progress-bar .content {
   white-space: nowrap;
   position: absolute;
   left: 23vh; /* will vary according to alignment */
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you provide your css class 'content' here?

However, assuming that you wanted the text "30% (3/10)" to be centered on progress-bar irrespective of the value.

Add css class to your progress-bar like below:

```
.progress {
       position: relative;
    }

.progress span {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    color: black;
 }
```

and your code should be like this:

```
<uib-progressbar animate="false" value="30" class="progress">
    <span class="content">30% (3/10)</span>
</uib-progressbar>
```

I have created a [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/bakawon/5/edit?html,js,output) for same.
This should work.

Comment: @Sumit Ramteke - Did this answer helped you?

Comment: Sorry @upasana, it worked just missed to mark this as accepted and also missed your previous comment. Not sure why ?